# /portfolios works but /portfolio doesn't

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and I've bought a theme. I've created a page with a permalink of `/portfolio`.

Whatever widget I place on that page does not render. It's like the theme itself doesn't like if you use the permalink `/portfolio`. Viewing the page renders like this:

[image]

The page is setup like so in wp-admin:

[image]

If I change the permalink to `portfolios` (or anything other than **portfolio** for that matter) instead of `portfolio`, they then display with the masonry layout, but now my URL is `/portfolios` I have only 1 portfolio, not multiple. What am I doing wrong here? I've been pulling my hair on this issue since yesterday.

**edit** 
I've gone back and forth with the theme's author support. There must be a language barrier or something because they are not understanding what I am trying to do.

I simply want my url to be `/portfolio`, not `/portfolios` or any other derived form of portfolio. The widgets just don't render if the permalink is `/portfolio`. What would be causing this?

Comment: do you have a custom post type called portfolio?

Comment: @Mark I don't believe so. The portfolio posts are using a plugin called "Opal Portfolios"

Comment: Very likely the plugin you're using is creating a custom post type called "Portfolio" and it's taking precedence in the URL mappings. If this is the case, you'd likely need to find a hook within the plugin to modify it before the custom post type is declared. Look in the plugin files for a function called `register_post_type()` - there is an argument you can pass called `redirect` which lets you define the url - right now it's probably 'portfolio'. With any luck this will be set dynamically somehow, allowing you to override it with a hook or the plugins settings.

Comment: Here is the relevant documentation from the WordPress Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#URLs_of_Namespaced_Custom_Post_Types_Identifiers

Comment: @JoshLaBau while I couldn't find something that says `register_post_type()` in my `wpo_portfolio.php` file, I did find a post_type reference to `portfolio` so I changed it to look like this: http://pastie.org/10377857 Line 43. I saved it, but it still isn't working. I suspect you're onto something though.

Comment: ok, I think I found the file you are talking about. It was located in `theme-name\wp-content\plugins\wpothemer\posttypes\portfolio.php`. The contents are here: http://pastie.org/10377895. If I change line 51 from `portfolio` to something like `portfolio-bad`, the page seems to be showing me the home page now

Comment: Change everything back to how it was - you'll still want to keep the post type named 'portfolio' since the rest of the plugin depends on that. However, we can change the rewrite URL so it doesn't interfere with your portfolio page. Luckily, this plugin allows us to override the function - not as good as getting a hook to change things, but better than writing directly to the plugin (which would break on updates). Once you have reverted back to the original code, paste this in your theme's `functions.php` file: http://pastebin.com/wfx1kXev

Comment: Thanks for the help so far @JoshLaBau. I reverted my files back and pasted that text in functions.php. It seems to be forwarding me to my home page now when I am at my /portfolio url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88050/discussion-between-josh-labau-and-ronnie).

Comment: I see you're running this on your local machine, have you tried uploading everything to a domain and seeing what happens. I've found that unless you have your local host install setup perfectly URL rewrites can be problematic.

Comment: @VirgilShelton no freakin way! How is that possible?! I happened to just move the wordpress site online last night rather than localhost. I just changed the permalink back to /portfolio and it's working. I don't believe it. If you make an answer, I'll accept it, but it'd be nice to know why

Comment: @Ronnie it's happened to me quite a few times, so much so that I stopped developing locally. It would be hard to pin down since it would take comparing your Webhost's Apache config with your localhost. I'll add the answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your issue you'll need to move your development environment from your localhost to your webhost.

Permalink issues are troublesome when working with WordPress and a localhost server environment. Apache on the localhost level can never match your hosts configuration and that's why I only develop remotely these days.

Comment: Thank you Virgil! Now I know not to develop WP on localhost

Comment: Not that I want to bring up old and already questions, but I have a problem. I went to permalinks and changed my `Category Base` to `.` and now `/portfolios` doesn't work again. I wanted to remove the `/category/` from breadcrumb links so I followed this http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/removing-category-base-urls-wordpress/ Once I saw it broke my `/portfolio` link, I deleted the `.` and now it is saying `Nothing Found - It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching can help.` with a search bar :( I def still have a page at `/portfolio` and it def still has posts at that url

Comment: I'm thinking it may have messed up my htaccess file somehow. All the other links work though which is weird. I am noticing if I go to `/portfolio/one-of-my-posts` I get a 404 not found, hmm. My custom structure for permalinks is `/%category%/%postname%/`

Comment: ok, I seemed to fix it. I disabled all the plugins and then reenabled them..I really dislike wordpress...never again

Comment: Glad you got it working Ronnie, yeah WordPress and permalinks can get frustrating!